# Dynamically adding Devexpress GridControl to C# windows application

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I want to add Devexpress GridControl dynamically. At runtime I want to show the Filter Row. Also I want to have a button on the same form that has the dynamically created GridControl. When the button is clicked it should show the Filter Dialog popup for the grid control.

Answer (score 6):

The provided sample does what you ask for.

- Create a Form called Form1.
- Create a Button called button1 and Dock it to
  the top of the form.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns;

namespace Samples
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private GridControl grid;
        private GridView view;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            view.ShowFilterPopup(view.Columns[0]);                      
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grid = new GridControl();
            view = new GridView();

            grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            grid.ViewCollection.Add(view);
            grid.MainView = view;

            view.GridControl = grid;
            view.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow = true;
            GridColumn column = view.Columns.Add();
            column.Caption = "Name";
            column.FieldName = "Name";
            column.Visible = true;

            // The grid control requires at least one row 
            // otherwise the FilterPopup dialog will not show
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Rows.Add("Hello");
            table.Rows.Add("World");
            grid.DataSource = table;

            this.Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And how to show the "Filter Editor" on button click. The same one that appears when you click on "Edit Filer" in the filter panel of the gridcontrol.

Comment: Ok , got it, it will be view.ShowFilterEditor(view.Columns[0]);
Thanks