# Dynamically created DevExpress DataGridView contains no data after setting DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have created a GridControl and GridView with the designer and set the DataSource and everything works fine. However when I create in code a new GridControl and a new GridView assigned to that GridControl and set the DataSource property correctly, then the GridView holds no data and RowCount returns 0.  Any ideas?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridControl1.DataSource = StraddleDataHandler.Data;

        GridControl g1 = new GridControl();

        g1.DataSource = StraddleDataHandler.Data;

        GridView v1 = new GridView(gridControl1);

        Console.WriteLine(v1.RowCount);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I set the DataSource property in my manually created grid control in designer, any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858077/dynamically-adding-devexpress-gridcontrol-to-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this does not solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648144/devexpress-refreshing-datagridview-in-vb-net-not-working/34675136#34675136

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this also does not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the BindingContext for the GridControl before it will generate.

```
g1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

The gridview is not being displayed with your code -- whatever was the default (main) grid view still is, even though you've created a second view.

As a result, DevExpress wisely (in my opinion) doesn't bother to render the grid view since it doesn't display.

If you make your view the mainview, I think you will see the rows appear.

```
GridView v1 = new GridView(gridControl1);
int before = v1.RowCount;  // 0, per your example
gridControl1.MainView = v1;
int after = v1.RowCount;   // now should have the correct rowcount
```

Just curious, but did you mean to do this instead?

```
GridView v1 = new GridView(g1);  // instead of gridControl1?
```

Comment: No, for demonstration purposes I was showing that the GridView showed data with gridControl1 and then the new one did not show with gridControl1, thanks anyways!